# Differences between servant, maid, page, and attendant

Tags: differences, early-modern-english, commonweath-english, professions

In an airplane, the lady attending you is known as the *attendant*, besides sometimes being called  a *stewardess* or  *air hostess*. What does she do? Just serve you.

Then what is that my *maid* does? Nothing but serve me. Can I therefore call my maid, my *attendant*?

What about my other servant? Can I call him my *attendant* too, since I cannot call a male person my *maid*?

Is gender the only difference?  Then who and what are *pages*?

I am looking for a clear distinction between these four terms.

Comment: You have servants?  *Really?*

Comment: Airline attendants are quite firm that their primary duty is to *attend* to the safety needs of the passengers. Coffee, tea or whatever is merely incidental. The term *maid* is based on the historic pattern of unmarried women primarily filling the role of domestic cleaners.

Comment: Did you look up their definitions? I feel like that would answer your question since your statement doesn't seem to take such definitions into account. Do attendant or page or servant have gender connotations as strong as stewardess or hostess or maid?

Answer (score 1):

Maid is a female domestic servant, whereas attendant is a person employed to provide a service to the public in a particular place. Maid is (female) gender specific, whereas attendant is used for both genders.

Page is usually a young boy in uniform attending a specific person or performing a specific duty like door attendant or errand.

A slave is a person who is the legal property of another and is forced to obey them.